# What exactly should the "meshes" folder have?

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, urdf, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While creating a gazebo simulation of any robot, we need to have a URDF so that Gazebo can understand the description of the robot and render it accordingly. Then what exactly is a `xacro` file ? Also I have observed a `meshes` folder many a times which contains all the `.dae` files. What exactly is it ?

Can someone provide a guide to understand all these simulation related concepts properly ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366100/what-exactly-should-the-%22meshes%22-folder-have-?/) by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2020-11-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-22**:
Some observations (but *not* answers, I'll leave that to someone else):

> While creating a gazebo simulation of any robot, we need to have a URDF so that Gazebo can understand the description of the robot and render it accordingly

actually, Gazebo doesn't use / understand URDF. It only uses [SDF](http://sdformat.org/). The reason you still see lots of `.urdf` and `.xacro` in Gazebo related packages is because Gazebo comes with a tool which -- on-the-fly -- converts your URDF into an SDF (as best it can, the process is not lossless).

Most pkg maintainers (including me) are just lazy, and prefer to only write and maintain a single model of a robot, so they use `.urdf` or `.xacro`, as they know that can also be used with Gazebo.

If you want to be really proper, you'd write a separate `.sdf` for the *simulation model of your robot*. The `.urdf` then describes the structure of your robot *to ROS* (ie: tells it where the sensors are, link lengths, etc). While the two would overlap ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-22**:
.. they are *not* the same. The latter is used by your control software (ie: ROS), the former is used by your simulator (ie: Gazebo), and they have different purposes and requirements.

Compare this to the situation where you have actual hw: no one expects to be able to use their URDF to produce or manufacture their real robot. Nor do they expect to be able to "spawn" their real robot using the URDF in the real world.

If you consider Gazebo as "a stand-in for reality", having to create a proper simulation model as an analog of your real hw, *and* additionally having a separate URDF (so not the same file) doesn't seem to strange any more.

> Also I have observed a `meshes` folder many a times which contains all the `.dae` files

I believe Wikipedia has a good description of what a "mesh" is: [wikipedia/Polygon_mesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh).

`.dae` is the file extension of [Collada files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COLLADA).

Note: this is not ROS specific.

**Comment by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on 2020-11-23**:
@gvdhoom Thanks for such a detailed answer. I would also like to ask how do we use the `.dae` placed in meshes in the Gazebo simulation ? Like does Gazebo 'refer' to them while creating the robot model or does it stand to be an alternative to be replaced by the robot SDF/URDF or what ? Basically what is the purpose of having the `meshes` folder in our ROS package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To add to @gvdhoorn's good information, `xacro` is a XML-based macro language to help with writing larger/more complicated URDFs as described [`xacro` wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro).  One example provided there is

```
<xacro:macro name="pr2_arm" params="suffix parent reflect">
  <pr2_upperarm suffix="${suffix}" reflect="${reflect}" parent="${parent}" />
  <pr2_forearm suffix="${suffix}" reflect="${reflect}" parent="elbow_flex_${suffix}" />
</xacro:macro>

<xacro:pr2_arm suffix="left" reflect="1" parent="torso" />
<xacro:pr2_arm suffix="right" reflect="-1" parent="torso" />
```

which expands to

```
<pr2_upperarm suffix="left" reflect="1" parent="torso" />
<pr2_forearm suffix="left" reflect="1" parent="elbow_flex_left" />
<pr2_upperarm suffix="right" reflect="-1" parent="torso" />
<pr2_forearm suffix="right" reflect="-1" parent="elbow_flex_right" />
```

Basically, if you have multiple arms, you can define it as a macro once, then use that macro to produce extra arms more efficiently/clearly.  The two arms in the example aren't so bad, but imagine defining 6 legs for a hexapod, with several links and motors each!

As for the meshes, the [URDF documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/link) provides an explanation of where URDF files use meshes.  Similarly, Gazebo uses meshes to define geometry.  They're often used to define more complex visual and collision elements, like in this brief [Gazebo tutorial for attaching meshes](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=attach_meshes).  The robot's model file (`.sdf` in this case) refers to the mesh from the chassis link's visual element like this:

```
<visual name='visual'>
  <geometry>
    <mesh>
      <uri>model://pioneer2dx/meshes/chassis.dae</uri>
    </mesh>
  </geometry>
</visual>
```

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2020-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1